# Kubernetes cluster internal routing not working (NodePort service)

Tags: routing, docker, kubernetes

I've been working on setting up a Kubernetes cluster for while now. My setup features two nodes and one master. All three machines are running on a Proxmox cluster and have 2 virtual network interfaces. One of the interfaces (listed below) is in a bridged network with the other machines. The other one is exposed to an internal network.

The network set-up looks like this for the bridged interfaces:

```
Network: 10.10.0.0  
Broadcast: 10.10.255.255  
Netmask: 255.255.0.0  

kubernetes-master IP: 10.10.0.1
kubernetes-worker01 IP: 10.10.0.2
kubernetes-worker02 IP: 10.10.0.3
```

All servers can talk to each other without any issues. I haven't set-up any kind of firewall yet.

```
root@kubernetes-master:~/manifests# kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS    AGE
10.10.0.2   Ready     5d
10.10.0.3   Ready     5d
```

I have a hello world nodeJS app that provides an HTTP server on port 8080 and displays "Hello world" when queried. It's set up like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-node-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-node
        image: kubernetes-master:5000/hello-node:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Then I created a new service that should expose the deployment via NodePort.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-node-service
  labels:
    app: hello-node
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-node
  type: NodePort
```

After starting both the service and deployment:

```
root@kubernetes-master:~/manifests# kubectl describe service hello-node-service
Name:           hello-node-service
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=hello-node
Selector:       app=hello-node
Type:           NodePort
IP:         10.100.0.88
Port:           <unset> 8080/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30862/TCP
Endpoints:      192.168.0.22:8080,192.168.0.23:8080,192.168.0.89:8080 + 1 more...
Session Affinity:   None
No events.

root@kubernetes-master:~/manifests# kubectl get pods --selector="app=hello-node" --output=wide
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
hello-node-deployment-815057587-0w896   1/1       Running   0          24m       192.168.0.89   10.10.0.2
hello-node-deployment-815057587-62d2b   1/1       Running   0          24m       192.168.0.23   10.10.0.3
hello-node-deployment-815057587-d6t4z   1/1       Running   0          24m       192.168.0.90   10.10.0.2
hello-node-deployment-815057587-k7qcx   1/1       Running   0          24m       192.168.0.22   10.10.0.3
```

After that the master can't contact any of the nodes on the provided node port (10.10.0.2:30862, 10.10.0.2:30862). The connection hangs and doesn't succeed.

If I connect to the node via ssh I can successfully query the service by directly talking to the pod:

```
root@kubernetes-worker02:~# curl http://192.168.0.22:8080
Hello World!
```

Am I missing something here? Is this the expected behavior or is my setup broken?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes requires more than just the nodes being able to talk to each other. It also requires a network (or routing table) so pods can talk to each other. It's essentially another network just for the pods (often called an overlay/underlay network) that allows pod on nodeA to talk to pods on nodeB.

From the looks of it you don't have pod networking set up. You can implement overlay networking a multitude of ways (which is one reason it's so confusing). Read more about the networking requirements [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/).

With only 2 nodes I would recommend you actually set up what I like to call "no SDN Kubernetes" and just manually add pod routes to each node. It would require you to do 2 things.

1. Specify the subnet for pods on each node
2. Manually run a command to create the route

I have details on how to do it on my [blog post I wrote about the subject](https://medium.com/@rothgar/no-sdn-kubernetes-5a0cb32070dd#.15leqarqq).

Unfortunately, setting up the pod networking is only going to get you 1/2 of the way there. In order to implement automatic NodePort services you also need to install the kube-proxy. The job of the kube-proxy is to watch for what port a service starts on and then route that port to the correct service/pod inside the cluster. It does this via IP tables and is mostly automatic.

I couldn't find a very good example of deploying kube-proxy manually (usually it's handled via your deployment tool) Here's an example of a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/daemons/) the [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) tool should automatically create to run the kube-proxy on every node in the cluster.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    component: kube-proxy
    k8s-app: kube-proxy
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    name: kube-proxy
    tier: node
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: kube-proxy
      k8s-app: kube-proxy
      kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
      name: kube-proxy
      tier: node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: kube-proxy
        k8s-app: kube-proxy
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
        name: kube-proxy
        tier: node
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - kube-proxy
        - --kubeconfig=/run/kubeconfig
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-proxy-amd64:v1.5.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kube-proxy
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/dbus
          name: dbus
        - mountPath: /run/kubeconfig
          name: kubeconfig
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
        name: kubeconfig
      - hostPath:
          path: /var/run/dbus
        name: dbus
```

One other resources that might be useful to go through is [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way). It's not directly applicable to running in VMs on proxmox (it assumes GCE or AWS) but it shows you the bare minimum steps and resources needed to run a functioning Kubernetes cluster.